# Flutter :go_router to pass the data of a list view to a detail page

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I want to open a detail page from a list view and not sure how to pass the value of the title clicked to other page

```
GoRoute(
  path: "/detailed_post/:title/:description",
  builder: (context, state) => DetailedPost(
    questionTitle: state.params['title']!,
    ),
  ),


class PostCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const PostCard({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<PostCard> createState() => _PostCardState();
}


onTap: () {    
  GoRouter.of(context)
            .go('/detailed_post/...);
      },
```

What should I put in the ... instead, thanks

Comment: just realised ${widget.title} will work fine with this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this trick:

```
onTap: () {    
/// adding 
  GoRouter.of(context)
    .go('/detailed_post/${widget.title}/...');
},
```

and in `DetailedPost` you can retrieve the value of your title parameter from `state.params['title']`.

happy coding...

Comment: yes, it works as it should, thanks a lot mate